# Sum of real numbers in intervals

Tags: real-analysis

My question is very simple, I consider two closed intervals of real numbers [$a$ , $b$] and [$c$ , $d$]. I want to show any numbers contained in [$a+c$ , $b+d$] can be written as the sum of two real numbers say $x$ of [$a$ , $b$] and $y$ of [$c$ , $d$]. I have tried by considering example but I require a general proof.

Comment: Let $w\in a+c, b+d$.  Then $a+c \le w \le b+d$ and $a \le w-c \le b+d-c =b+(d-c)< b+ 0 =b$.  So $x = w-c \in [a,b]$.  And $y= c\in [c,d]$.  That's it.  Maybe you want something were $x,y$ are somehow proportional so we aren't always doing $y=c$.  Maybe something like for $w\in [a+c,b+d]$ let $r=\frac {w-(a+c)}{(b+d)-(a+c)}$. (Note: $0\le r \le 1$).  Then let $x=a+r(b-a)$ and $y=c+r(d-c)$.

Comment: Keep in mind the interval notation implies inequalities. From there, you need to apply an additive rule for inequalities.

Comment: What does the set $[a, b] + x$ look like for fixed $x$?

Comment: @anomaly we can write x as [x, x] so [a,b]+[x,x] =[a+x,b+x] from basic rules of interval analysis

Comment: OK, and note that $[a, b] + [c, d] = \bigcup_{x\in [c, d]} ([a, b] + x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be the set you describe. We know that the addition map $+ : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Therefore $M$, as the image of the path-connected set $[a,b] \times [c,d]$ under $+$, is path-connected.

We easily see that $a+c, b+d \in M$. It follows that $[a+c, b+d] \subseteq M$, which completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try representing any number as the sum of $3$ numbers $a+c+k$, and see if you can find a way to generally combine $k$ with $a$ or $c$

Answer (score 0):

Brainstorm:  If $a+c \le w \le b+d$ then $w$ is "some proportion" between $a+c$ and $b+d$.  Pick $x,y$ so that the are the same proportion between $a$ and $b$ and $c$ and $d$ respectively.  How?

Let $r = \frac {w- (a+c)}{(b+d)-(a+c)}$.  Thats the "some proportion". Note: $0 \le r \le 1$.

Let $x = a + r\times (b-a)$ and $y = c+ r\times (d-c)$.  Those are the same proportion.

$a=a + 0\times (b-a) \le x = a+r\times(b-a) \le a+ 1\times (b-a) = a+ b -a=b$.  So $x \in [a,b]$.  Same argument that $y \in [c,d]$.

And $x + y = a + r(b-a) + c + r(d-c) = $

$(a+c) + r[(b+d) - (a+c)]=$

$(a+c) + \frac {w-(a+c)}{(b+d)-(a+c)}\cdot [(b+d) - (a+c)]=$

$(a+c) + (w - (a+c)) = w$.

.....

Or if you don't want to do so much math.

$a+c \le w \le b+ d\iff a \le w-c \le b+d-c$

And

$a+c \le w \le b+d \iff a+c-b \le w-b \le d$

Case 1:  $w-c \le b$.  Then $w-c \in [a,b]$ and $c \in [c,d]$.  Let $x=w-c$ and $y=c$.

Case 2:  $w-c > b$.  Then $w-b > c$.  So $w-b\in [c,d]$ and $b\in [a,b]$.  Let $x = b$ and $y= w-b$.

Comment: cause it was late and I was tired and I ... confused

Comment: Ooog.  Things seem so much clearer in the morning.